# jQuery datatables exporting data to Excel

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, export

I am trying to export directly from the datatable to Excel.

Starting with the ajax call:

```
displayRecords();
function displayRecords()
{
  $.ajax({
    url: 'process/getRecords.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: '',
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
    {
      var jsonObject = $.parseJSON(data); 
      var table = $('#resultsTable').DataTable({    
      {
        "data": jsonObject,
        "columns": [
          {"data": "JOB_REFERENCE"},
          {"data": "VOYAGE_REFERENCE"},
          // few more columns
        ],
        "iDisplayLength": 25,
        "scrollY": 500,
        "scrollX": true,
        "bDestroy": true,
        "paging": true,
        "stateSave": true
      }
    },
    error: function(jqHHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
      console.log('fail: '+ errorThrown);
    }
  });

   // button click to export results
   var tableresults = $('#resultsTable').dataTable();

   $("#btnExport").on('click', function(e) 
   {
     e.preventDefault();
     window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' +
       encodeURIComponent(table[0].outerHTML));
   });
}
```

Using all of the above, I can successfully export the results from the datatable.  I can even use the filter search to drill down to a smaller data set, and export the results.

I was using the following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/donpayne/jzdjdo3z/

The problem I am having lies with the Show Entries dropdown of the datatable.  Typically, the dropdown is set to 10.  Whether you filter the search down or not, if the total record count is greater than the Show Entries dropdown, the Excel sheet will only return the total amount set in the dropdown.

You can test what I am talking about in the fiddle.  Set the Show Entries dropdown to 10, then export to Excel.  If you'll notice, there are 58 total records in that table.  The Excel sheet will only return 10 records.

I need the to return all the records.  If I have 2000 records, and the Show Entries dropdown is set to 10, I need the exported Excel sheet to include all 2000 records.

The same if I filter the search down to about 56 records; when I export to excel, I should have a total of 56 records on that spreadsheet, regardless of what the Show Entries dropdown is set to.

As stated, I referenced the code from the fiddle and altered it to fit my datatable.

Comment: I worked on this for a bit - my solution was to use table.page.len(-1) to disable paging then restore it. but it occurred to me - you're possibly trying to pass 2000 rows of data through through a url string, aren't you?  Aren't you limited in the amount of data you can pass through there?

Comment: @dgig - I am not limited to the amount of data.  I just picked the number 2000.  Although, currently, the table I am working with does have a little over 2100 records.  This table could hold more or less.  I hope that answers your question.

Comment: Might help: https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/export.html

Comment: @KarloKokkak - I was able to achieve the results I needed thanks to your suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best thing to do is to remove the paging, then do the export, then turn the paging back on once it's done.

I made a couple minor changes:

```
$(function () 
{
    var table = $('#example').DataTable();

    $("#btnExport").click(function(e) 
    {
        table.page.len( -1 ).draw();
        window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + 
            encodeURIComponent($('#example').parent().html()));
      setTimeout(function(){
        table.page.len(10).draw();
      }, 1000)

    });
});
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jzdjdo3z/176/

Page Length docs: https://datatables.net/reference/api/page.len()

Paging option docs: https://datatables.net/reference/option/paging

I'm not sure why initializing with dataTables vs DataTables made a difference, but it did. So keep an eye out for that.

Comment: I'm getting this error: Cannot read property 'len' of undefined.  I didn't see the additional links you provided.  checking again.

Comment: No longer getting the len error, but now the excel sheet is only showing 'No data available in the table.'  The datatable does clear out when I click the export button.  Not sure if that has something to do with it.

Comment: Did you make all of the changes I did in the fiddle? There's quite a few that are important even if they don't seem to be. The dataTables --> DataTables for one. When you use my fiddle, what do you see when you open the downloaded file? I see basically an html table with all 58 of your records.

Comment: Yes, my javascript matches your javascript except for the name of the datatable, which in my case is #resultsTable.  When I click the export button, the datatable clears out, and the excel sheet returns only the text 'No data available in the table', which is the text after the datatable clears out.  I'm going to fine tooth it, but everything appears to match.

Comment: Hm. It shouldn't clear out, that's a problem for sure - `table.page.len( -1 ).draw();` means basically remove any pagination. Did you see the comment from Karlo btw? https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/export.html It seems to have a built in function for excel exports. This might be what you need instead of rolling your own?

Comment: Oh, I wonder if the fact that we're reinitializing the table again with DataTables is a problem because we're not giving it data. Maybe skip that second `var tableresults = $('#resultsTable').DataTable();` and just call `table.page.len(-1)` on the variable you created from your ajax call. That's the only thing I can think of.

Comment: I appreciate all of your input.  Although promising, I have not been successful.  I cannot seem to figure out what my datatable blanks out.  Your fiddle seems to work, and I've mimicked the code.  I guess I'll have to abandon this process and go with what works.  I thank you for your help.